# Merge Sorted Linked Lists with head node

Tags: c

I am writing a void function void merged_lists (cell * l1, cell * l2, cell * l3); who receives two linked lists, headed by l1 and l2, whose content is ordered in non-decreasing order, and generate a new list headed by l3 that contains the elements of l1 and l2 ordered.

If the list headed by l1 is l1 -> 1 -> 7 -> 9 -> 10 -> NULL and headed by l2 is l2 -> 2 -> 3 -> 8 -> NULL, for example, the output must be l3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> NULL

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void display (node *le){

    node *p = le->next;

    while(p != NULL ){
        printf("%d -> ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");

}

void MergeLists(node *l1, node *l2, node *l3) {
  if (!l1) 
    l3 = l2;
  if (!l2) 
  l3 = l1;

    //Chosing head of merged list
  if (l1->data < l2->data) {
    l3->next= l1;
  } else {
    l3 = l2;
    l2 = l1;
    l1 = l3;
  }

  while(l1->next && l2->next) {
    if (l1->next->data > l2->data) {
    //Step 1. Save the next pointer
      node *tmp = l1->data;
    //Step 2. Change next pointer to point L2
      l1->next = l2;
    //Step 3. Move L2 to temp
      l2 = tmp;
    }
    //Step 4. Move L1 ahead
    l1 = l1->next;
  } 
  if (!l1->next) l1->next = l2;
  display(l3);
}
```

My output for l1->1->7->9->10->11 and l2->2->3->3->8 is 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 7 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> NULL.

Any tips on how to solve this problem at the beginning?

(I know I posted a similar question earlier, but as the focus changed, I thought it was fair to do another post)

Comment: The best tip is to learn to debug effectively. Have you run your program in a debugger and/or added more debug print statements to trace the execution of your program? If you want further help here please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068589/merge-sorted-linked-lists-with-head-node)

Comment: You may find [Singly Linked List of Integers (mergesort)](https://pastebin.com/CsBYkjrq) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a first problem with this code

```
if (!l1) 
    l3 = l2;
if (!l2) 
    l3 = l1;
```

You override `l3` with the value of `l2` or `l1`. The result is a memory leak because the head node `l3` was referring to has no more references.

If the caller had a reference on the head node of `l3` he will still see an empty list after the call because the head node of `l3` has not been modified.

You should copy all the nodes of `l1` or `l2` into `l3` so that `l1` and `l2` are left unmodified and `l3` is a copy of one of them.

There is also a problem with this code

```
//Chosing head of merged list
if (l1->data < l2->data) {
    l3->next= l1;
} else {
    l3 = l2;
    l2 = l1;
    l1 = l3;
}
```

You assign to `l3->next` the head node of `l1`. This means that the first node after the head node of `l3` is the head node of `l1`. Since the head node does not contain a relevant value, this yields a wrong result.

Another problem is in the `else` block. Again, you override the value of `l3` and thus loose the reference to the head node of `l3`. The caller of the `MergeLists` function won’t see a change in `l3`. It will still be an empty list after the call.

Another problem is that the following line won’t compile. Did you really compile and run your program ? `l1->data` is of type `int`, not of type `node*`.

```
node *tmp = l1->data;
```

I stopped reading your code here because it didn’t made sense.

The correct code is as simple as this

```
void MergeLists(node *l1, node *l2, node *l3) {
    node *l1p = l1->next, *l2p = l2->next, l3p = l3;
    while (l1p != NULL || l2p != NULL) {
        if (l1p != NULL && (l2p == NULL || l1p->data < l2p->data)) {
            l3p->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
            l3p = l3p->next;
            l3p->next = NULL;
            l3p->data = l1p->data;
            l1p = l1p->next;
        } else {
            l3p->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
            l3p = l3p->next;
            l3p->next = NULL;
            l3p->data = l2p->data;
            l2p = l2p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes that `l3->next == NULL` when starting executing the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my first solution was something like that.  I'm trying to solve it without allocate any new cells in function, just manipulating the pointers from nodes of l to be in l1 and l2. Therefore, the use of "malloc" function is "banned". I forgot to put this condition in the statement, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60072608/4139593) answer, `l1` inside the function `MergeLists` points to the start of a linked list but `l1` is local to `MergeLists`.

Changes done on `l1` or `l2` or `l3` will not be reflected in the caller module.

You need to pass a pointer to pointer (sometimes called a 'double pointer' but that's ambiguous with `double *`) to reflect on caller function.

Here is the snippet without allocating extra memory `node`s are merged,

```
void MergeLists(node *l1, node *l2, node **l3) {
    if (!l1) {
        *l3 = l2;
        return; //no mearge required
    }else if (!l2){
        *l3 = l1; //no mearge required
        return;
    }

    node tempHead;
    node*tempPtr = &tempHead;

    while (l1 && l2) {

        if (l1->data < l2->data)
        {
            tempPtr->next = l1;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }
        else {
            tempPtr->next = l2;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        tempPtr = tempPtr->next;
    }

    if (!l1)
        tempPtr->next = l2; //l1 is empty remaining l2 is appended to the merged list
    else
        tempPtr->next = l1; //l2 is empty remaining l1 is appended to the merged list
    *l3 = tempHead.next; // temporary head is copied back to the caller
}
```

which should be called like `MergeLists(l1, l2, &l3);` but make sure that `l1`,`l2` will no more pointing to the initial list.

You can find complete code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SJnxOLuML).